# duplicate files in Groups & Files tree

Tags: xcode

When adding an existing file to the project, the entire subdirectory it was in got inadvertently added, so now 136 resource files each show up twice in the Resources folder of the Groups & Files tree.  I tried ungrouping/regrouping etc. but they're still there twice. App works fine but I get 136 warning messages when building.  I know I can delete and re-add the files, but I'd like to just delete the superfluous Groups & Files reference.

Does anyone know how to "delete" an entry in Groups & Files without affecting the physical files on disk?

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the extra copies from the group by selecting them and hitting delete. You'll be prompted to Remove Reference Only or Delete. If you click on Remove Reference Only, it will be removed from the group but will remain on disk. If you click on Delete, it will delete the file from the group and from the disk.